# c# detect directory change

Tags: c#, directory, filesystemwatcher

I use FileSystemWatcher in C# to monitor a directory.  It is well documented (and well complained about) that FileSystemWatcher works fine to detect changes in the directory, but not changes to the directory.  To get around that I am checking directory existence every second but what a waste.  I need to know if something changes in the directory and if the directory is deleted or renamed.  Is there a better way without polling?

Comment: How about monitoring the parent directory of the directory you are interested in?

Comment: the parent directory is C: ... so there would be continuous changing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could monitor parent directory AND set Filter property to your folder's name to get only events for the folder AND set IncludeSubdirectories to true.

Comment: The problem with that approach is... how far do you go?

Say I have C:\Foo\Bar\Monitored

Monitored is the directory I really want to monitor.
But, if Monitor is renamed, I wouldn't know.
So, i'd have to add another Filesystemwatcher for Bar.
But if that one is renamed, I'd need one for Foo.
If that one's renamed, ..

Surely, there must be a better way?